# Problems when trying to install SQLite3

Tags: npm, sqlite, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed SQLite3 successfully (I think), however when I try to `node index.js` I get the following:

```
sudo npm install sqlite 3 --unsafe-perm
...

+ 3@2.1.0
+ sqlite@2.9.2
added 4 packages and updated 1 package in 320.95s
```

*node index.js*

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

    Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi/Documents/Angel/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v57-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Documents/Angel/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed "sqlite" and "3", as NPM tells you
That is because you have a whitespace between sqlite and 3, so npm thinks those are two different things you want to install
Try with `npm install sqlite3`